# Getting Accuracy from Prediction using ML.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, machine-learning, formula, ml.net

I have a system where it predicts which football position the players is the most suitable for him based on his skills/attributes.

**Now as a results i am getting like the below**

```
Lionel Messi
CAM - 65%
ST - 12%
.. etc
```

and the accuracy of all the other remaining positions which amount to 10 in total

I am predicting a total of 20 players.

How can i get out the accuracy of the algorithms pls any formula i can use? Thanks